# Data Site Issue: Is this a Bug or Hack?

Tags: support, data-explorer, login

When I logged in some one else (jon.doe15661) seems to be using my picture and login in the data site. Is this a bug or some one hacked my account?

[image]

Comment: @ChrisW Moved the issue here.

Comment: @abbyhairboat any idea what is going one here?

Comment: Did you log out and re-logged in with the jon.doe account with your password? What do you exactly mean with your _login_?

Comment: No. I when to the site. I was not logged in. So I clicked login followed by clicking the SE login logo then entered by usual email and password. I clicked on my profite to see what tabs / tables / information it might have and then I got this.

Comment: Do you know the alias 'jon.doe'? If yes, it is _most likely_ a bug, if you don't than I would not take any risk and change your password immediately. This could also be a [merge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) problem (if you have used the merge tool in the past).

Answer (score 1):

Integration between SEDE and other sites is imperfect.

The "someone else" is probably you?

Perhaps when you logged in it was able to get your existing avatar but not your existing user name (and you can fix it by defining/setting your user name within the SEDE profile).

I see (by zooming into the screenshot you posted) that you're using a `openid.stackexchange.com` open ID.

Comment: I always use login with SE. The 1st logo on the login page.

Comment: [Why am I jon.doe when logging into Data Explorer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85265/139866)

Answer (score 0):

Almost everyone is jon.doeXXXXX when they first log in to Data SE.

In your screenshot, look in the topbar: you are logged in as jon.doe15661. It's not that some Jon Doe is using your picture; it's that you have been assigned a name at random because of the [weird way Data SE picks up user info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85271/165581).

Feel free to edit your display name with the edit link you see on that page.